# Promise constructor and "Property 'handleEvent' is not callable" error

Tags: javascript, promise

this code returns the above error - why ?

```
function rej(params) {
}
function res(params) {
}

let func = new Promise(function (res, rej) {
});
```

What am i doing wrong?

### edit

Some extra info (as suggested in the comments)

I'm trying to understand the Promise constructor and how to use it. I'm not asking for techniques to solve a problem, I simply try to understand it.
it is simple to use the promise by chaining `then`'s to it. what i ask is about the constructor.
thanks

Comment: `let func = new Promise` No, `func` is a Promise, not a function - `new Promise` returns a Promise instance

Comment: @CertainPerformance I understand. so, what use do i have for the constructor in that context?

Comment: To help you fix this wrongly structured code, we need to understand what problem you're trying to solve.  What do you want the btn click listener to do?  It would probably be more useful for us to help you solve your actual problem rather than try to explain why when you pass something other than a function to a listener, you get this specific error.  Also, your definition of `res` and `rej` looks wrong too as those functions are created by the promise itself and passed to the promise executor callback function.  You call then, you don't create them.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: @jfriend00 i thought so as well, but please check the "Chaining after a catch" section and example on mdn. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

Comment: @yossi - I have no idea what that comment means.  I see no chaining anywhere in the code you show.  I repeat.  If you want help, tell us what you are trying to accomplish.  This code is so far from correct, we can't tell what you are trying to do.

Comment: @jfriend00 they use the same syntax as i did. here: another example from the page `const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));`
seems like the resolve and reject are callbacks that CAN be set outside the executioner

Comment: They do NOT use the same syntax you are using here.  You create a promise, put nothing inside the executor function so that promise will NEVER be rejected or resolved and then you pass a promise to an event listener which makes no sense at all.  MDN doesn't do any of those things.  Plus your variable named implies that you think `func` is a function.  It is not, it's a promise.  There is literally nothing correct in the code you show except `var btn = document.getElementById("_btn");`.  So, we can't help you until you explain IN WORDs what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am i doing wrong?

First off, this code:

```
let func = new Promise(function (res, rej) {
});
```

Creates a promise that is never resolved or rejected.  One should have code inside that callback function that does something asynchronous and then when that asynchronous operation completes, it calls once of the two functions passed to that callback `res(value)` or `rej(reason)`.  The two arguments for this callback function here:  `function (res, rej) {` are functions that the promise created and passed to the callback.  Your job as the creator of the promise is to call one of those some time in the future.  A promise that has no code that ever calls one of those is of no use.  It's just an object that never does anything.

Second, this code also assigns that newly created promise to a variable named `func`.  That implies that you think it's a function.  It is not.  It's an object, more specifically a promise object.  You can't call that object like you can a function.

Third, you then take that promise and pass it as a callback function here:

```
btn.addEventListener("click", func);
```

`addEventListener()` needs that 2nd argument to be a function.  You passed a promise which is not a function.  That's a calling error.

---

Without further description (in words) of exactly what you are trying to accomplish, we can't make more specific coding suggestions other than to answer your direct question and explain what you are doing wrong with the code you show.

---

Also, keep in mind that promises are one-shot devices.  They can never be resolved or rejected more than once.  As such, they often don't match very well with event listeners when the event can occur more than one time (like a button click) unless you only ever want to know about the first click and no subsequent clicks.  They do match up well with events that only occur once such as `finished` or `close` or some event like that.

Answer (score 0):

anytime you use the `new` operator, you are returning a non-function object. A Promise is not a function.

```
let func = function(e){
    return new Promise(function (res, rej) {
        return ...
    }); };
```

Also, you don't need to define res and res functions, they are built into the Promise. 
Read the Promise API!